# How to expand field initializers in xtend annotation processor

Tags: annotations, xtext, xtend

I am using Active Annotations to generate fields in my classes and am having difficulty discovering how to expand field initializer expressions. Without initializers the code looks like this

```
class JavaFxPropertyProcessor implements TransformationParticipant<MutableFieldDeclaration>{

def private transform(MutableFieldDeclaration field, extension TransformationContext context){
    fields.forEach[transform(context)]
}

def private transform(MutableFieldDeclaration field, extension TransformationContext context){

    val clazz = field.declaringType as MutableClassDeclaration
    val theClass = SomeJavaClass //any non-parameterised java class here

    clazz.addField("myField")[
        type = theClass.newTypeReference
        initializer = ['''new <<toJavaCode(theClass.newTypeReference()>>(this)''']
    ]       
  }
}
```

This works fine when the field has no initializer. Ocassionally, I would like the field to have an initializer and that works fine for `int` and `bool` literals by just dumping the initializer as a string into the expression

```
val theInitializer = field.initializer //this is not null
    clazz.addField("myField2")[
        type = theClass.newTypeReference
        initializer = [
        '''new <<toJavaCode(theClass.newTypeReference()>>(this, <<theInitializer.toString>>)'''
        ]
    ]
```

When the initializer is a list literal, say `#[1,2,3]` for example, then clearly the naive `initializer.toString` technique doesn't work since it creates java code such as

```
val myField = new List<Integer>(#[1,2,3]);
```

So how to I get to evaluate/expand the `field.initializer` (which is of type `org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro.expression`) in order to java-ise it for my initializers?